# How can I get other layer in the same scene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have several layers in the scene, like TLayer,HLayer,TouchLayer. How can I get HLayer in HLayer? The solution I take is that I pass Layer to other Layer. However I met some problems recently. I push the Scene and pop Scene while TouchLayer still exists. So my problem is that is it right to pass HLayer to TouchLayer. Or is there a better way to do it in Cocos2d-x?

In the init() function in Scene:

```
this->setbackgroundLayer(BackgroundLayer::create());
CC_BREAK_IF(!backgroundLayer);
this->addChild(backgroundLayer);

this->setTLayer(TcharacterLayer::create(backgroundLayer->tianzige));
CC_BREAK_IF(!TLayer);
this->addChild(TLayer);

this->setHLayer(HcharacterLayer::create(testCharacter,backgroundLayer->tianzige_draw));
CC_BREAK_IF(!HLayer);
this->addChild(HLayer);

this->settouchLayer(TouchLayer::create(TLayer,HLayer));
CC_BREAK_IF(!touchLayer);
this->addChild(touchLayer);
```

I made my own create function:

```
TouchLayer* TouchLayer::create(TcharacterLayer* t,HcharacterLayer* h){
    TouchLayer* pRet = new TouchLayer();
    if (pRet && pRet->init(t,h))
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }else
    {
        delete pRet;
        pRet = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how we've done this in the past. Define a set of tags for our layers.

```
typedef enum {
    kBgLayerTag,
    kHLayerTag,
    kTLayerTag,
    kTouchLayerTag
    } MyLayerTags
```

Then while creating the layers set layer specific tags:

```
this->setTLayer(TcharacterLayer::create(backgroundLayer->tianzige));
CC_BREAK_IF(!TLayer);
TLayer->setTag(kTLayerTag);
this->addChild(TLayer);
```

And in TouchLayer access the TLayer and others like:

```
TcharacterLayer* myTLayer = this->getParent()->getChildByTag(kTLayerTag);
```

Comment: Where can I define those enum. I think it is a global variable.

Comment: You're right it has to be in a common header file. I usually define a constants.h for such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is nothing wrong in adding a layer as a child. I would do that this way :
BackgroundLayer has all the necessary layers as children (remember to add TouchLayer as the last one and then pass Touch to others) and then you only add BackgroundLayer to your scene. There is even more simple way (probably better): to make BackgroundLayer inherit all the previous ones - but that depends on how much scenes you are going to make.

Edit:
1)

```
BackgroundLayer * bglayer = BackgroundLayer::create();
TcharacterLayer * tcharlayer = TcharacterLayer::create();
HcharacterLayer * hcharlayer = HcharacterLayer::create();
TouchLayer * tlayer = TouchLayer::create();

bglayer->addChild(tcharlayer);
bglayer->addChild(hcharlayer);
bglayer->addChild(tlayer);
this->addChild(bglayer);
```

(assuming this as a CCScene)

2)

```
class BackgroundLayer : public TcharacterLayer, HcharacterLayer, TouchLayer
{
...
}
```

In the first case you can give each layer a specific tag and then get the layer by `getChildByTag(int tag)` or just create fields in the BackgroundLayer class for each layer.